# OData Expanding fields and filtering by them

Tags: filter, odata, sitefinity

I am trying to do an odata request with the following URL and it works:

```
https://localhost:44379/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers?$expand=RelatedTeam,Offices,RelatedExpertise,RelatedLocation
```

However when I add a filter like this:

```
https://localhost:44379/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers?$filter=(contains(Title,'j')) and RelatedLocation/Id eq 69dce15b-6194-4d87-9090-7e5278267284&$expand=RelatedTeam,Offices,RelatedExpertise,RelatedLocation
```

It does not work.
The goal is to get all teammembers that have a location with an id of 69dce15b-6194-4d87-9090-7e5278267284 and a title that contains 'j'. Is my syntax wrong or something else?

Is there a way to do this as a select query. It appears that this is a sitefinity bug: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/OData-Query-filter-by-parent-dynamic-content-item-custom-field

Comment: According to this article: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/manage-the-properties-of-a-type navigational properties (such as the related data in Sitefinity) do not support filtering and sorting. Might be easier if you create the web service yourself

Comment: ya, i ended up doing some custom stuff myself instead